Everything keeps moving to the opposite of what I have selected
For example, I have a simple cereal box shape with 6 sides. If I click on the front face to extrude it, the back face is what actually moves. If I click on the left face, the right face is what actually moves.
Likewise if I am trying to uv map graphics, if I click on the left edge, the right edge is the one that moves. If I click on the bottom edge, the top edge is the one that moves.
I tried googling this but just kept getting results for other things. The one thing I frequently came across was making sure the little dropdown at the top of the screen for "Transform orientation" was set to global or default. Default doesn't seem to be an option and I'm in global already.
Any help much appreciated! New-ish to blender and don't use it often but I'm pretty sure this wasn't the way it worked last time I was using it!!!
Thanks
Edit:
Thanks for your reply moonboots! I didn't include a screenshot as it would need a video really. But if I have this right face selected and then move the red axis, the left face will go back and forth instead of the one I have selected.

Hello please show a screenshot

added! Thanks :)

Have you tried applying Scale and Rotation to your object with Ctrl+A ?

You have both Snapping and Proportional Editing enabled on the top toolbar (two hilighted icons in the centre) which might be giving you unexpected results. Try clicking on each to disable them and see if that improves matters. If not, please share your file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
